# Is there a full list of the parameters supported by the Facebook search API?

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api

There is a search API can be used by developers to conveniently query posts, people in Facebook. But is there a full list of the parameters supported by the Facebook search API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook official docs provide what you need .graph api reference page has nice table describing what are various fields that can be used to call graph api.

Few links to use graph API and its reference

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/**

Github gist of Facebook Cheatsheet

https://gist.github.com/stevedev/1097432

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. Though the Facebook API had been changed several times since the question was posted:)

Answer (score -4):

Ill assume you did not find/read their website on FQL, so Ill give you that address now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: I've read this document. But there's only very limited information about the parameters available. For example, the q parameter supports OR operation by |, which is not even mentioned there.

Comment: FQL has no search function.... what I say about search API is supported by Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ , not FQL. One can't search over all the posts by FQL.